# Generic Input Filter

Tags: angular

I needed a generic filter for inputs so that I didn't have to write ng-model logic every time.

My solution:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="foo" input-filter="-?[0-9]*" />
```

Code Behind

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener, ElementRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][input-filter]',
    providers: [NgModel]
})
export class InputFilter {  
    @Input('input-filter') filter: string;
    private regEx: RegExp;
    private previousValue: string;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private ngModel: NgModel) {        
        this.previousValue = '';
    }

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
        if (!this.regEx) {
            this.regEx =  new RegExp(`^${this.filter}$`);
        }

        if(this.regEx.test(this.ngModel.value)) {
            this.previousValue = this.ngModel.value;
        }
    }
    @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onKeyUp(event) {
        let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;

        if(this.regEx.test(this.ngModel.value)) {
            return;
        } else {
            this.ngModel.update.emit(this.previousValue);
        }
    }   
}
```

This solution works, but I was curious if anyone had a better way.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE

I asked the question too soon.  The original directive didn't update the model (silly me).  The new code does update the model.

The filter is passed in via attribute on the input element.

Comment: `filter` value is available only when the event is trigerred and not during the `constructor`

Comment: Have you tried using reactive forms instead of template driven forms in Angular?  I think you'll find it a lot easier and it means less has to be put into your templates and more logic is contained within your controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to validate the input and not allow the user to inter wrong values, you are on the right way but you are missing some points.

You should add your custom validators like the native ones(ex : required).

[Hope this article will help you.](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html)